# Start program via SSh and then close tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have got a little python program which I want to run on my remote sever(Ubuntu). But after closing the ssh-connection the program closes as well.

How do I keep this program running without the ssh-connection?

Comment: Think perhaps you're probably either looking to daemonize your python script, or run process in the background? http://www.astro.ku.dk/comp-phys/tutorials/background.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of simple things to try -

1. Add an "&" character to the end of the command line you are running which will background the job and will probably work or
2. Use the "screen" program - run screen, then the command, then detach your console from screen.

Comment: Option 1 worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the program screen.
Once logged in to the SSH session, type:
 `screen -S (name)`

Then start the process. Disconnect by typing:
`Ctrl-A then D`

When you want to re attach to this session, SSH back in and type:
   `screen -r (name)`